# How to get values from a method to ajax in .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

this is my jQuery code on submit button

```
function SubmitFilter()
{ 
    var transactionNumb = $("#transactionNumber").val();
    var cardHolderName = $("#cardHolder").val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://localhost:7197/Transactions?transaction_number="+transactionNumb+"&cardholder="+cardHolderName,
    
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) 
    {
      alert(data);
    }
    });

}
```

And this the code behind class from here I'm not able to call the GetTransactions method directly..ajax method goes to onget method only.

Here my intention is to get the jarray value in ajax success function
you can look full code if you need in this link
https://technotesfromwork.blogspot.com/2022/07/tech-note.html

please let me know how i can change this code to return the jarray value to ajax. thanks in advance..

```
 public void OnGet(int CurrentPage,int transaction_number, string cardholder)
    {
            this.Authorize = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Roles");
            this.CurrentPage = CurrentPage; 
            if(CurrentPage==0)
            {
               this.CurrentPage = 1;         
            }
            ViewData["Title"] = "Transactions List";
          
            Transactions =  GetTransactions(this.CurrentPage,transaction_number,cardholder);   
           
    }
    public JArray GetTransactions(int currentPage,int transaction_number , string cardholder)
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", HttpContext.Session.GetString("JwtToken"));            

            var url = $"{BaseApiUrl}/transactions?page={currentPage}&limit={PageSize}";    
            var filters ="";
            
            var requestUri = new Uri(url);

            var responseTask = client.GetAsync(requestUri);
            responseTask.Wait();
            var result = responseTask.Result;
            
            // this.TotalResults = result.Headers.GetValues("X-Paging-Pages");
            this.TotalResults = "5";

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var reportResults = Task.Run(async() => await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>()).Result;                  
                return reportResults;
            }
        }

        return JArray.Parse("[]");
    }
```

Comment: It will be very helpful if you provide the error details.

Comment: actually I'm not able to call the GetTransactions method directly..ajax method goes to onget method only.
Here my intention is to get the jarray value in ajax success function you can look full code if you need in this link https://technotesfromwork.blogspot.com/2022/07/tech-note.html

Comment: When trying to learn a new technology start from its own documentation and `Getting Started` tutorials, not random blog posts. `Ajax` is the name given in the 2000s to what to day is just a plain old HTTP call, available through JavaScript with `fetch`. ASP.NET Core already serializes responses as JSON, there's no need to construct JSON results by hand. The code you posted though looks like a *Razor Pages* page, not a Web API controller. A Page's `OnGet` returns the HTML page to the browser.  You need a different method for that *and the tutorials already show this*

Comment: The `GetTransactions` method itself should be discarded, plain and simple. It's full of serious bugs, including blocking an asynchronous operation. If that was a code interview, whoever wrote this would fail instantly. HttpClient instances are meant to be reused, not disposed. *All* this code could be replaced with a single `var transactions=await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<Transactions>(url);return transactions;`

Answer (score 1):

Create a handler to retrieve a JSON result for the ajax call :

```cs
public void OnGetAsJson(int CurrentPage,int transaction_number, string cardholder)
{
    this.Authorize = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Roles");
    this.CurrentPage = CurrentPage; 
    if(CurrentPage==0)
    {
        this.CurrentPage = 1;         
    }
    ViewData["Title"] = "Transactions List";

    var transactions = GetTransactions(this.CurrentPage,transaction_number,cardholder);
    
    return new JsonResult(transactions);
}
```

and change the ajax url to this :

```js
function SubmitFilter()
{ 
    var transactionNumb = $("#transactionNumber").val();
    var cardHolderName = $("#cardHolder").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://localhost:7197/Transactions?handler=AsJson?transaction_number="+transactionNumb+"&cardholder="+cardHolderName,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) 
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Or even remove jQuery and use `fetch`. Both JS and ASP.NET Core are far simpler than the question's code

Comment: And `GetTransactions` itself should be deleted and replaced with just `var transactions=await _client.GetFromJsonAsync(url); return transactions;`

Comment: Hi i tried this above set of example (OnGetAsJson method and ajax ) but  the ajax method not calling to OnGetAsJson method. It's directly calls to default onget method..

Comment: Did you change the URL ? use the URL provided in my answer, you have to add '?handler=AsJson' to the URL

Comment: Yes exactly i used same url.. with    ?handler=AsJson

Comment: @VasanthR instead of trying to fix this bad code you should learn how to use Razor Pages. Start with [Introduction to Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). This explains that the HTTP methods are handled by *handler* methods. To call methods beyond the default you have to [specify their name in the URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#multiple-handlers-per-page) **BUT ...  Using a Razor Page to handle API calls is a terrible** idea.

Comment: @VasanthR your code will be a *lot* cleaner if you use a separate Controller for the API calls. Use Razor Pages for what they're meant to be, render HTML and handle pages. Use API controllers for what they're meant to do

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I'm just updating my client code we cannot say this thing to client like you've to learn from this documentation.. we've change.. but thanks for your idea

Comment: Hi @VasanthR, how do you invoke the `SubmitFilter`? Be sure it is not a button or input without specifying the type. It must specify `type="button"`. Otherwise it will do form submit by default.

Comment: Hi @Rena It's <a> tag  like this one <a href="#" onclick="SubmitFilter();">SUBMIT</a>

Comment: Hi @VasanthR, Maybe I suggest you can share your whole code to us and edit your previous question. Actually Almost's shared solution is correct.

Comment: you can check my full code here https://technotesfromwork.blogspot.com/2022/07/tech-note.html#main

Comment: Hi @VasanthR, not exactally, you need follow the Almost's solution and add a `OnGetAsJson` method. What you shared is just the old code demo.